# Github API 502 error

Tags: api, curl, github

I'm trying to add a user to a Github repository via their API, but I always get a `502 Bad Gateway` error. 
With curl I send a request like this (<...> replaced by a real owner, repo, etc.):

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxx' -XPUT https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/collaborators/<username>
```

I also tried it with this url:

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxx' -XPUT https://api.github.com/teams/<id>/members/<username>
```

As token I used a newly created *Personal Access Tokens*

But both times I get this back

```
HTTP/1.0 502 Bad Gateway
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
</body></html>
```

A `GET` on each URL works fine but a `DELETE` doesn't work either. So maybe it has to do with curl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the reply from GitHub's support with changes in italic:

> You're just getting trolled by HTTP and curl.
>
> When you make a PUT request with no body, curl doesn't explicitly set a Content-Length header for that request. However, PUT requests with no Content-Length confuse servers and they respond in weird ways.
>
> Can you please try explicitly setting the Content-Lenght header to 0, or supplying an empty body when making that request (so that curl can set the header for you)? 
>
> You can accomplish that adding
>
> ```
> -d ""
> ```
>
> in your command.